# Narrow band extensible message format

Tags: xml, embedded, compression

I'm putting together a technical response to tender, one of the requirements is to pass messages using an extensible format over a narrow bandwidth network (10 bytes/sec or so). To make life easy on the server, which will be receiving info from 1000's of devices I'd like to use Xml. To help with the bandwidth issue I could use compressed Xml, but the data is coming from embedded devices that might not have the omph to do compression on the fly. Anyone got any better ideas, an ideal would be a small extensible format, that could be hyrdated into Xml once the messages have been received over the narrow band.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

> Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats.

Comment: There's also a .net version - http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ just what I need - cheers

Answer (score 0):

[YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) is a very terse format ideal for passing serialized information between devices. There are libraries available for most programming languages, so the server could probably understand it directly and there wouldn't be any need to convert to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info would be useful. As it's stated the answer could be ASCII. Were you thinking of transmitting numbers, floats, degrees, names? Perhaps something more esoteric like ASN.1. Or you could go completely mad, as with the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, Google Protocol Buffers or Apache Thrift are very popular binary serialization tools.  That said, they do have some overhead because they tag each field (to achieve a limited form of backward/forward compatibility as you change the schema).

[Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html) doesn't do that tagging and will save you a tiny bit more space because of that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you won't be making the server's life easier by using XML.  XML parsing code is complex if you use any "features" of XML (namespaces, entities, escaping, internationalization, etc), and parsing XML is usually slower than parsing other formats such as JSON.  You can write a simple JSON encoder/decoder in a page of code, whereas XML and even YAML will require more complexity.  Avro and Thrift and Google Protocol Buffers are good choices though you will be increasing your dependency footprint.

If you're really restricted to 10 bytes / sec then you will likely want an encoding that doesn't have a lot of quoting or syntax; a hand-crafted length-prefixed protocol, or something like protobuf's binary encoding, is probably what you want.